# Phonegap network status in windows mobile

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, status

I have used  below function for check network status in windows mobile simulator. It returns "unknown" either ethertnet present or not.

```
function checkConnection() {
var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
```

}

```
checkConnection();
```

Comment: Have you tried it on a device?

Comment: on Windows mobile or Windows Phone?

Comment: @RaoulGeorge I have tried with the simulator.

Comment: @DocRoms Windows phone

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Phone, For get The current interface you can use the class 'NetworkInterfaceList' :

```
NetworkInterfaceInfo CurrentInterface;
var interfacesList = new NetworkInterfaceList();

foreach (NetworkInterfaceInfo specificInterface in interfacesList)
{
    CurrentInterface = specificInterface;
    break;
}
```

You can Subscribe to an event for the network changement :

```
DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += NetworkChanged;

private void NetworkChanged(object sender, NetworkNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    CurrentInterface = e.NetworkInterface;
}
```

After get the current interface, you can get the true type of network :

```
switch (CurrentInterface.InterfaceType)
{
    case NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet:
        // ETHERNET (USB connected)
        break;
    case NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma:
        switch (pNetworkInterfaceInfo.InterfaceSubtype)
        {
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_GPRS:
                // 2G
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_EDGE:
                // 2GP
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_EVDO:
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_EVDV:
                // ?
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_1XRTT:
                // ?
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_3G:
                // 3G
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_HSPA:
                // 3GP
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Unknown:
                // Unknonwn ? 4G is Unknown.
                break;
        }
        break;
    case NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm:
        switch (pNetworkInterfaceInfo.InterfaceSubtype)
        {
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_GPRS:
                // 2G
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_EDGE:
                // 2GP
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_EVDO:
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_EVDV:
                // ??
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_1XRTT:
                // ??
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_3G:
                // 3G
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_HSPA:
                // 3GP
                break;
            case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Unknown:
                // Unknown? 4G is Unknown
                break;
        }
        break;
    case NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211:
        // WIFI
        break;
}
```

Note that with a Windows Phone 7 project, We haven't a "4G type", When I test the 4G with a device, The NetworkInterfaceType is unknown... but, if we have a network problems in 32G or 3G, is Unknown too..

I've not test with a Windows Phone 8 project, but, in theory, that works in 4G.

Also, you can have more details on the Networks type [here](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod%C3%A8le%3aPalette_Normes_de_t%C3%A9l%C3%A9phonie_mobile).

PS: For test the network, there is nothing better than testing with a real device, and therefore, a real network.